# Which video formats does QuickTime Player's Touch Bar support?

Tags: macbook-pro, video, big-sur, quicktime, touch-bar

Some video files, when played with Apple's QuickTime Player on a macbook pro, show thumbnails on the Touch Bar that you can "scrub" through to quickly peek around.  Others don't.  Is there any documentation about which formats *do* work?

Even sticking to the h264 codec, I've found no yes/no pattern in aspect ratio, resolution, or frame rate, never mind the thousand other things that ffmpeg can tweak.
If it matters: Big Sur 11.6.4, MacBook Pro 16" 2019, i9, 32 GB.